# Trying to read a text file in Python, getting IOError(2, 'No such file or directory')

Tags: python, import

so I'm trying out this ScrabbleCheat challenge from https://openhatch.org/wiki/Scrabble_challenge

I followed the code found here, placed it into a project in PyCharm, but getting stuck on the `f = open(input_file, 'r')` line, says it can't find my sowpods.txt file :(

[image]

Now when I try the code from the terminal it will actually run! :( However I'm trying to build an interface for my project so would like to get out of the terminal as quickly as possible.

[image]

The text file is in the right place

[image]

Problem code, any thoughts?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from flask import Flask
import string
import sys
import sqlite3 as sqlite

app = Flask(__name__)


def test_for_db():
    # test for existance of  sowpods database
    pass


def test_for_sowpods():
    # test for existence of sowpods  text file
    pass


def word_score(input_word):
    # score the word
    # need to account for the blanks
    scores = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
            "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
            "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
            "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
            "x": 8, "z": 10}

    word_score = 0

    for letter in input_word:
        word_score = word_score + scores[letter]

    return word_score


def word_list(input_file):
    # create a list of tuples which containing the word, it's length, score and sorted value

    sp_list = []
    f = open(input_file, 'r')

    for line in f:
        sp_word = line.strip().lower()
        sp_list.append((sp_word, len(sp_word), ''.join(sorted(sp_word)), word_score(sp_word)))

    f.close()

    return sp_list


def load_db(data_list):

    # create database/connection string/table
    conn = sqlite.connect("sowpods.db")

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # create a table
    tb_create = """CREATE TABLE spwords
            (sp_word text, word_len int, word_alpha text, word_score int)
            """
    conn.execute(tb_create)
    conn.commit()

    # Fill the table
    conn.executemany("insert into spwords(sp_word, word_len, word_alpha, word_score) values (?,?,?,?)",  data_list)
    conn.commit()

    # Print the table contents
    for row in conn.execute("select sp_word, word_len, word_alpha, word_score from spwords"):
        print (row)

    if conn:
        conn.close()


def print_help():
    """ Help Docstring"""
    pass


def test():
    """ Testing Docstring"""
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    # test()
    sp_file = "sowpods.txt"
    load_db(word_list(sp_file))
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What's the process's current directory when running from PyCharm?

Comment: How are you calling `word_list()`? What's the `input_file` parameter set to?

Comment: Please paste text, not screenshots.

Comment: Also, you're misusing the word (and tag) "import" here, which makes things a bit confusing. You import modules. You open, and read, text files.

Comment: sorry peepz, added the full code now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path `"sowpods.txt"` means "The file named `sowpods.txt` in whatever directory happens to be the [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) at the moment."

If you want "The file named `sowpods.txt` in the same directory as the script", you have to say so, like this:

```
import os
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

sp_file = os.path.join(scriptdir, "sowpods.txt")
```

---

Note that in a real-life program or module that you plan to distribute, you'll probably want something a little more complicated, where your `setup.py` file configures an appropriate (for each machine) location for the file. (You can't rely on scripts and their data files being installed alongside each other on most platforms.)

---

If you run the script from the command line, the current working directory is obvious, because you can see it in the shell. For example, on Windows:

```
C:\> C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\me\MyScripts\myscript.py
```

… the current working directory here is `C:\`. To make it work, you'd have to do this:

```
C:\> cd C:\Users\me\MyScripts\
C:\Users\me\MyScripts\> C:\Python27\python.exe .\myscript.py
```

If you run the script by double-clicking it, where it runs depends on your OS and version—it may be your system's root directory, or your home directory, or something else entirely. There's probably *no* way to make it work.

And if you run the script from inside an IDE, it's probably configurable by the IDE. In PyCharm, it's part of your project's "Run/Debug Configuration".

But really, you don't want a script that can be used only when you do things exactly in a certain way; you want a script that works however you run it.

Comment: Thanks, had no idea that my project's file structure was causing the problem :)

Comment: @LeonGaban: It's not your project's file structure that's causing the problem; it's that you're making an unwarranted assumption about your current working directory. The current working directory can be _anywhere_, so unless `sowpods.txt` is _everywhere_, you can't reliably find it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a relative path for your input file, which means your script will only work if you are running your script with the same working directory as your "sowpods.txt" file.  Switch to using a full path, so your script will work no matter what the working directory of the script is.

Here's how:  In your `if __name__=='__main__':` block at the end, instead of using

```
sp_file = "sowpods.txt"
```

use the full path:

```
sp_file = "/Users/leongaban/scrabblechallenge/path/to/your/file/sowpods.txt"
```

(of course substituting whatever the full path to your file is)

When you create a GUI for your program, you could have the user choose the file, and call `word_list` with the resulting file path as the argument.

Comment: Thanks this worked! And yeah I'm a front-end guy, already have that part taken care off, trying to get this back end to work. But yeah I prefer relative paths, @abarnert's solution fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying the following

```
import os
#get the directory your script is located in which also has the file you're trying to read
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
fullpath = os.path.join(path,input_file)
f = open(fullpath,"rt") # instead of your current open
```

Answer (score 1):

Brionius' answer works, but isn't portable for when you want to move your script somewhere else.

What you're experiencing is actually a problem with your PyCharm configuration. You'll want to change your PyCharm working directory, as documented [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-python.html). Namely, you'll want to change your working directory to where "sowpods.txt" is currently located.